# Why would both regular and minified Bootstrap CSS be referenced in code?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, minify, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to implement a third-party script which references the following in its demo template:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prettify.js"></script>
```

Both bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css are included with the script, which is understandable, in case the user wants to modify an unminified script.  But why would the author reference both in the HTML code?

P.S. I can't easily tell if there are any differences in the two files, because the unminified script has over 6000 lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be (if it is live). Just the minified should be referenced.

Referencing both is redundant and a waste of resources - unless one or both of the files contain custom adjustments. But then they should be combined to one to save http requests.

If it is in development, it is sometimes handy to reference a non-minified version when tweeking - though then I wouldn't bother with a minified version then.

EDIT/UPDATE: If this is straight from a template and no one has worked on your website, then I suspect the template references both to make it easy to chose which one you want - it is sometimes easier to develop with the full file.

If your site is small you can just reference the minified version and go through it to ensure that all works.

If no work has been done, so no chance of custom changes, just get rid of the one you do not want.

Answer (score 3):

This is a clear demonstration of incompetence of the developer. You only need one or the other. Minified is the most recommended to reduce the bandwidth consumed by the site. First you write normally, and when you insert it in the website, you minify it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just for demo purposes or something. It really doesn't make a difference (except load redundant files). Yes, the minified version is just a condensed version of the original file and that's why it has fewer lines.

In production code, both should not be referenced.